# Python, Pandas, Dataframes: Inexplicable characteristic difference that I cannot identify

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In a code base that has worked wonderfully for a long time, suddenly I have a crash. I have traced it nominally to a Pandas idiosyncrasy that has be confused. Essentially I have two CSV files, a reference and a result and I load each of these into a dataframe for a subsequent comparison.

But out of the blue, two CSV files that looks comparable to me, certainly have the same shape, and same characteristic content, load in very different ways, one of them very cryptically, with the `read_csv()` method. I have skipped the first line in e each file which has the column headers and used a custom set. This dialog with Python illustrates the problem in a way I find hard to explain in natural language. But if I must it is this: Two seemingly identical dataframes, in shame, and character, behave very differently when sliced.

In the following python dialog you will see that reference behaves as expected, and result for some reason when slicing one column out, returns a 2D thing, and yet, that is judged purely on the repr, the actually types and dimensions of the slices agree. In this example I'm slicing column 2.

It looks almost as if result in column 2 has the whole CSV row. Problem is if I slice column 1 or 0 or 3 or 4 I get the same result!

What could be causing this oddity, that makes it very hard for me to compare slices?

```py
>>> reference = pandas.read_csv(reference_file, skiprows=1, header=None, names=column_names, delimiter=delimiter, low_memory=False)
>>> result = pandas.read_csv(result_file, skiprows=1, header=None, names=column_names, delimiter=delimiter, low_memory=False)
>>> type(reference)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> type(result)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> reference.shape
(70698, 1426)
>>> result.shape
(70698, 1426)
>>> reference.iloc[:, 2].size
70698
>>> result.iloc[:, 2].size
70698
>>> reference.iloc[:, 2]
0       -9.900000e+37
1       -9.900000e+37
2       -9.900000e+37
3       -9.900000e+37
4       -9.900000e+37
             ...     
70693   -9.900000e+37
70694   -9.900000e+37
70695   -9.900000e+37
70696   -9.900000e+37
70697   -9.900000e+37
Name: Distance_vl, Length: 70698, dtype: float64
>>> result.iloc[:, 2]
0      0.000000  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  464.0  NaN        NaN         -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
1      0.000000  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  514.0  20.276414  -87.380000  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
2      0.000320  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  914.0  20.276409  -87.380000  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
3      0.000325  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  920.0  20.276409  -87.380000  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
4      0.000485  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:45  146.0  20.276406  -87.380000  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
                                                                                                                                                          ... 
70693  2.473177  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  15:09:15  24.0   20.278198  -87.381172  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
70694  2.473177  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  15:09:15  76.0   20.278198  -87.381172  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
70695  2.473177  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  15:09:15  147.0  20.278198  -87.381172  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
70696  2.473177  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  15:09:15  159.0  20.278198  -87.381172  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
70697  2.473177  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  15:09:15  267.0  20.278198  -87.381172  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
Name: Distance_vl, Length: 70698, dtype: float64
>>> type(reference.iloc[:, 2])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> type(result.iloc[:, 2])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> reference.iloc[:, 2].size
70698
>>> result.iloc[:, 2].size
70698
>>> reference.iloc[:, 2].shape
(70698,)
>>> result.iloc[:, 2].shape
(70698,)
>>> type(result.iloc[:, 2][0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> type(reference.iloc[:, 2][0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> result.iloc[:, 2][0]
0.0  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  464.0  -999.0  -999.0  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
Name: Distance_vl, dtype: float64
>>> type(result.iloc[:, 2][1])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> result.iloc[:, 2][1]
0.0  -9.900000e+37  1970-01-19  13:54:44  514.0  20.276414  -87.38  -1.524544  1.524544  -1.524544  1.524544  2800  0.0  ...  0.0    0.0
Name: Distance_vl, dtype: float64
```

**Note:** `result.iloc[:, 2]` has very long lines of 0s, and SO can't take all the data, so I inserted elipsis (...) manually on its repr to post here.  Essentially it looks like the repr of `result.iloc[:, 2]` is showing `result` not one column of it.

Comment: Your result_file has changed format. If you open both csv files it should be apparent. If not you can post a few lines and we can help further.

Comment: Happy to do that, but it doesn't explain the inconsistency between the repr of `result.iloc[:, 2]` and its shape. I am hoping to learn what in Pandas is broken here or if not broken, a rather undiscoverable property it seems.  To summarise though, there are these known differences:

1. reference has a 3 byte BOM and result does not.
2. reference lists 0 to 6 db and result 1 dp (decimal point)
3. result has some number differences
4. result has a couple of nan strings  (as in `,nan,`)
5. the format is otherwise the same, comma separated numbers

Comment: What do you mean by 3 byte BOM? What does that look like? Items 2,3,4,5 should have no effect.

Comment: My guess is that the result_file was not saved as utf-8 or utf-16 , either way its missing the byte order marking. If you open it and save it as utf-8 it should read into pandas correctly.

Comment: The BOM is the byte order marking and in the reference file is EF BB BF, and none exited in the result file. Added it to the result file (in a hex editor) and alas the problem persists. Notepad++ opens the files and they look the same, in format. While I may find a format issue (and can work at stepwise experiments) none of it explainshow Pandas can have two Series of same shame but one has a sensible Series repr and the other a weird repr.

Comment: I added some diagnostics to the OP. Turns out the individual elements of the `result.iloc[:, 2]` are Series, while they are Floats in `reference.iloc[:, 2]`. The result has not returned column 2 per se, but a Series which has as each element a Series which looks like the whole line! I see this is a Pandas bug one way or the other. It's confounding confusing behaviour.